# How to read, find and replace using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a plain html page here:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a id="email" href="{email]">click me</a></li>

  <li><a id="yt" href="{youtube}">click me</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Don't mind the {} there. And i wanted my js to read and write(find and replace email and youtube with the values from sessionStorage.)How could i do that? please help.

Comment: regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

Just select the element and replace the href attribute with whatever value you get from [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

```js
const replaceText = (id, replaceStr) => {
  let el = document.getElementById(id);
  
  if (el) {
    el.href = replaceStr;  
  }
};

replaceText('email', 'test@test.com');
replaceText('yt', 'https://www.youtube.com');
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="email" href="{email}">click me</a></li>

  <li><a id="yt" href="{youtube}">click me</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yeah that is one way, but i will also be burning this data into this html, So like to be more clear i have a react app that takes and stores data into the sessionStorage and i want to use a js function to read and write(burn) data into the html file.(I know fs doesn't work with react but i am using electron js so how could i do it then?